# Как использовать KeyVault сущности в коде после сборки фоновой службы?

Tags: c#, azure

Есть фоновая служба, которая при запуске собирает конфигурацию и использует `KeyVault` службу.

```cs
IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configBuilder) =>
    {
        var configuration = configBuilder.Build();

        configBuilder
        .AddAzureKeyVault(
            new SecretClient(
                new Uri(configuration["KeyVaultUri"]),
                new ClientSecretCredential(configuration["KeyVaultTenantId"], configuration["KeyVaultClientId"], configuration["KeyVaultApplicationSecret"])
            ),
            new KeyVaultSecretManager()
        );
    }
```

Все запускается и работает.

Но внутри данной службы ниже по иерархии я хочу использовать некоторые сущности, например не только `ConnectionString`, но и дополнительные секреты, которые нужны для взаимосвязи с внешним API. Под эти запросы написан отдельный класс, который сейчас содержит секреты прямо в коде, что и не есть хорошо

```cs
public class RequestsService : IRequestsService
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    private string? accessToken;

    public const string BASE_URL = "https://www.host.com/api";
    public const string TOKEN_URL = "https://id.host.com/connect/token";

    // TEST instances
    readonly string clientId = "****";
    readonly string clientSecret = "****";

    public RequestsService()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }
   // дальше пошли методы запросов
}
```

Вопрос: как пробросить секреты до данного класса? Как ими воспользоваться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение.

Сначала добавил в сущности KeyVault

```
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name "ApiAccess--ClientId" -SecretValue (ConvertTo-SecureString "*********" -AsPlainText -Force)
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name "ApiAccess--ClientSecret" -SecretValue (ConvertTo-SecureString "*********" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

И добавил конфигурацию в конструктор, объявив переменные, которые буду использовать в коде.

```cs
public class RequestsService : IRequestsService
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    private string? accessToken;
    private readonly string clientId;
    private readonly string clientSecret;

    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public const string BASE_URL = "https://www.host.com/api";
    public const string TOKEN_URL = "https://id.host.com/connect/token";

    public RequestsService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Configuration = configuration;
        clientId = Configuration.GetSection("ApiAccess")["ClientID"];
        clientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("ApiAccess")["ClientSecret"];
    }
   // дальше пошли методы запросов
}
```